# AngularJS HTTP - brokes JSON index's positions

Tags: angularjs, json, http-request

I'm making $HTTP.GET request and this is my output content:

```
{
  "hierarchy": {
    "101": {
      "166": true
    },
    "29": true,
    "26": {
      "30": true,
      "181": true,
      "33": true
    }
  }
}
```

The problem here is that I got wrong index's position in the JS Object...
I think while javascript decodes json_data it's sorts index positions and I got something like this :

```
{
  "hierarchy": {
    "26": {
      "30": true,
      "33": true,
      "181": true
    },
    "29": true,
    "101": {
      "166": true
    }    
  }
}
```

I think the reason of that is because indexes are Numbers(INT). I cant change the structure of receiving Data. So I need to keep the index positions of Object - it's very important.

How can I tell to Angular HTTP.GET/POST method not to sort the response?
Or any ideas what can I do?

Comment: 1st place why you wrote a code based on `index`, you should consider a key..or better re-format the json in object pattern

Comment: Object properties are not ordered. You will get a different order depending on the browser, user, time-of-day, etc etc. Use an array if you need order.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the solution is to reformat the response data - order items by keys (simple array).